# how to debug use node-inspector at meteor.startup

Tags: meteor

I try to debug meteor with node-inspector.

There are two '.js' files on /server directory:

main.js

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    var a = 1;
    var  b =2;
    console.log(a+b);
});
```

test.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    hello:function(){
        var c = 3 ;
        var d = 4;
    }
});
```

at first,I set the environment  `NODE_OPTIONS='--debug'`
and run`meteor` . at another CMD run `node-inspector`

I open `localhost:8080/debug?port=5858` at chrome
and find the file "app/server/main.js" and set a debug flag on 3 line. like this:

```
 
(function(Npm, Assets){(function(){Meteor.startup(function(){
    var a = 1;
    var  b =2;  //debug at here
    console.log(a+b);
});

})();

})
```

but nothing happen and  at cmd the result of `console.log(a+b);` have already print. at other hand, if i set a debug flag in "app/server/test.js" and the run `Meteor.call("hello")` at console of `localhost:3000` then  the breakpoint can work well .

at above ,I  failed to debug on `Meteor.startup`.

the next,I try to use `NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk'`

I rerun  `meteor`  and  refresh  `localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`

It will break at

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { process.argv.splice(2, 0, 'program.json');
```

and then I press `F10` again and again , the debug flag  nothing seems to be happening at `app/server/main.js`. at the same time ,if debug at test.js  and call `Meteor.call` at client chrome .the breakpoint can also work well.

How can I debug at the function `Meteor.startup(function(){...})`

What's the step I have forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

there's a [issue related to node-inspector](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1411). Depends of your version, maybe you can try to [downgrade to 1.10](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/MeaC-E_Sj6Q).